# Hadoop dfsadmin -report command is not working in mapr

Tags: hdfs, mapr

I need to know the dfs report of the mapr cluster but when i am executing following command i am getting error

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

report: FileSystem maprfs:/// is not an HDFS file system
Usage: java DFSAdmin [-report] [-live] [-dead] [-decommissioning]
```

Is there any way to do it in MAPR.

I tried [this](http://answers.mapr.com/questions/1229/dfsadmin-report-and-fsck-equivalent.html) link as well but it doesn't provided needed information.

Comment: Why are you appending "/" in the end? It is not needed.

Comment: @ManjunathBallur it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Try below commands:

```
maprcli node list
maprcli dashboard info
```

Comment: `-bash: maprcli:` **command not found**. The message is *"... Instead use the hdfs command for it."*. There are a `hdfs` command for a complete report?